# Add Title Header to Dialog Box Using Pine Script TRADINGVIEW

Tags: pine-script

I want to add a header title within the Dialog Box where the user can customize the values to his studies.

I tried using the "input" element that includes "title", but they don't behaves like a header title.

Could it be possible?

Comment: How will you use this title in the future?

Comment: Hey @AnyDozer ...its purpose is to identify different sections within the panes inside de Dialog Box

Comment: Read the section at the link https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-organize-my-scripts-inputs-in-the-settingsinputs-tab

Answer (score 0):

Use the `group` property when declaring inputs. This will add a section header to the input dialog box.

Example:

```
useStartPeriodTime = input(true, "Start", input.bool, group = "Date Range", inline = "Start Period")
startPeriodTime = input(timestamp("20 Jan 2021"), "", input.time, group = "Date Range", inline = "Start Period")
useEndPeriodTime = input(true, "End", input.bool, group = "Date Range", inline = "End Period")
endPeriodTime = input(timestamp("20 Feb 2021"), "", input.time, group = "Date Range", inline = "End Period")
```

[image]

https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/organize-script-inputs-in-sections-and-lines-23321/